# Sybase drop primary key

Tags: key, sybase, ddl

I have the following table in Sybase

```
create table CUE_LOAD (
CAR_YEAR               numeric(4,0)                     not null  ,
CAR_ACCT                      numeric(15,0)                    not null  ,
CAR_INIT_DATE                date                             not null  ,
CAR_END_DATE           date                             not null  ,
CAR_DOCTYPE               varchar(20)                      not null  ,
CAR_DOC_NO               varchar(20)                      not null  ,
CAR_CONCEPT                    varchar(100)                     not null  ,
CAR_NAME                varchar(100)                     not null  ,
CAR_SHOP_VALUE                numeric(20,0)                    not null  ,
CAR_VALUE_IVA                   numeric(20,0)                    not null  ,
CAR_VALUE_RTF            numeric(20,0)                    not null  ,
CAR_CONSIG                  varchar(30)                      not null  ,
CAR_ID                          int                              identity  ,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( CAR_ACCT, CAR_DOC_NO, CAR_INIT_DATE, CAR_END_DATE )    on 'default')
```

As you can see we have a composite primary key on it and it has no constraint name, but now we need to drop it and assign the primary to another column in the table, i've tried with

```
ALTER TABLE CUE_LOAD DROP PRIMARY KEY
```

But i get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PRIMARY'", I've also tried with

```
ALTER TABLE CUE_LOAD DROP PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( CAR_ACCT, CAR_DOC_NO, CAR_INIT_DATE, CAR_END_DATE )
```

but same error appear.

So how i can drop this primary key ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I finally figure it out, execute the command  sp_helpconstraint CUE_LOAD to find the primary key identifier asigned by Sybase something like CUE_LOAD_11311480441, then use the drop constraint command

```
ALTER TABLE
CUE_LOAD
DROP CONSTRAINT CUE_LOAD_11311480441
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
sp_dropkey PRIMARY, CUE_LOAD
```